# Setting style.display on an array of id's in HTML - GoogleScripts / JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, google-apps-script

Essentially I am return an array of values that will either be " " or "X". When It's "X" I would like the element to be shown (which it is on page load), and when it's " "(blank) I'd like the element to be given

```
style.display = 'none';
```

Here is my Script so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function onSuccess(id) {
   for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
   if (id[i] == '') {
       var td_mod = document.getElementById(i);
       td_mod.style.display = 'none';
      }
   }
}
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).returnAch();
</script>
```

And here is the function "returnAch();"

```
function returnAch() {
//return the ARRAY of all 'X'

    var sheet =  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Achievements');
    var value = sheet.getRange("E1:E100").getValues();

//Logger.log(value + "<--- Values of 'x'");

    return value;
}
```

I've tested "returnAch()" and it logs the entire array of values - I'm just unsure which part of the HTML I'm messing up.

Thanks for any and all help!

Comment: What are the elements that you are displaying/hiding?

Comment: Images like this:                                                                <td><img border="0" id="8" src="http://i.imgur.com/VQrKvwc.png" width="772" height="72"></td>  - I've tested it with some hard written code and I can hide/show the td elements

Comment: Have you tried logging intermediate values in your onSuccess function? (Like the id variable passed in, how many times you hit the id[i] == ''" case, the td_mod element itself). It also seems possible that some other code (the spreadsheet code, perhaps?) is undoing your work afterwards -- you could try throwing an error or displaying an alert after your code is done (but before onSuccess returns) to see if that's the case.

Comment: Thanks, that worked well - I'll update the question with the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I figured out I wasn't calling the GoogleScript Function Correctly,

Html / Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function onSuccess(id) {
   for(var i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
   if (id[i] == '') {
      var td_mod = document.getElementById(i-1);
       td_mod.style.display = 'none';
       console.log(td_mod);
      }
   }
}
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).returnAch();
</script>
```

Google Script:

```
function returnAch() {
 //on call return if there is an x at pos "loc" 
  //return the ARRAY of all 'X'
  var value =     SpreadsheetApp.openById(SPREADSHEET_ID).getSheetByName("Achievements").getRange("E1:E100").getValues();
  //Logger.log(value + "<--- Values of 'x'");
  return value;
}
```